# Notepad++ ( perl ) regex match multiple line pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove a div from a couple hundred html files

```
<div id="mydiv">
    blahblah blah
    more blah blah
    more html
    <some javascript here too>
</div>
```

I thought that this would do the job but it doesn't

```
<div(.*)</div>
```

Does anyone know which is the proper regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**

```
<div[^>]+>(.*?)</div>
```

Don't forget to check the option `. matches newline` like in the image below : [image: dot matches newline checkbox - Notepad++ v6.2.3]

Alternatively, you can use this regex also: `<div[^>]+>([\s\S]*?)</div>` with or without the checkbox checked.

**Discussion**

Since `*` metacharacter is greedy, you need to tell him to take as few as possible characters (use of `?`).

Check that the divs you want to remove DO NOT contain nested div. In that case, the regex at the start of my answer won't help you.

If you face this case, I'd suggest you using an html parser.

Comment: i tried your edited reply, still doesn't work. no, there are no nested divs

Comment: life saver. thanks! though this seems to do the trick too : <div(.*)</div> i just needed to check the match newline